# Postgres recovering

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database 9.0.4 who is used by a software called Jasperserver, in a Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.2 server. During my vacations this software stopped working, and my coworker restarted the server. Now we can't connect to the database

```
[root@OHS jasperreports-server-6.0]# ps aux | grep postgres
postgres 12791  0.2  0.0 159424  4520 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 /app/jasperreports-server-6.0/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /app/jasperreports-server-6.0/postgresql/data -p 5433
postgres 12792  0.0  0.0 159560  2744 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 postgres: startup process   recovering 0000000100000000000000CE                                        
root     12856  0.0  0.0 103240   876 pts/0    S+   16:23   0:00 grep postgres
```

in postmaster.log file:

```
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2017-11-03 15:55:51 WET
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/CE529088
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  redo starts at 0/CE529088
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  record with zero length at 0/CE5A4DB8
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  redo done at 0/CE5A4D78
[2017-11-07 16:22:24 WET] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2017-10-20 01:48:13.275987+01
[2017-11-07 16:23:19 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:24 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
[2017-11-07 16:23:27 WET] FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

I don't have any database backup.
What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any database backup. What can I do to resolve this problem?

1. Immediately shut down the medium.
2. Make a block-level reproduction of the partition that hosts the tablespace.
3. Mount that reproduction under the latest version in the 9.x release, which is 9.0.23
4. If it starts up, thank the gods.

Other options,

- Cry, join irc.freenode.net #PostgreSQL and find people who know how to do manually recovery of tablespace. Expect to spend $2k-5k.

Generally you can pull some tricks to find `0/CE5A4D78` and clear out subsequent transactions and you'll be ok. The data is there, it's just not consistent and proper. At this point though, without a test case, I think it's out of the realm of DBA.SE and you need a consultant.